# How to extract raw query from dbr golang query builder

Tags: mysql, database, go

I'm new to the golang `dbr` library (https://godoc.org/github.com/gocraft/dbr)
and I did not find an information about how to get a raw query using this library.

I need something similar to `get_compiled_select()` from php igniter. I need it to combine multiple complex queries with union.

Answer (score 7):

The following will dump the query...

```golang
stmt := session.Select("*").From(table).Where("id = ?", ...)

buf := dbr.NewBuffer()
_ = stmt.Build(stmt.Dialect, buf)
fmt.Println(buf.String())

// print the interpolated values
for _, v := range stmt.WhereCond {
    fmt.Println(v)
}
```

Note that the output will not include the interpolated values.

Comment: stmt.Dialect is not a valid property using `github.com/mailru/dbr`, import `github.com/mailru/dbr/dialect`, then use `dialect.Sqlite` for example. upvoted anyways.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not so sure previous answer (setting the struct as public) is the wise solution, even if that's works.

IMO, better solution would be creating new getter function inside select.go

```
func (sel *SelectStmt) GetRaw() string {
return sel.raw.Query 
}
```

With this method, it should be easier to maintain.

Comment: You can't do this unless you are editing the dbr package itself.

Answer (score -3):

u can set raw struct from expr as public.

I hope it helps u.

Comment: You can't do this unless you are editing the internals of the dbr package itself.